# Is it possible to animate two objects in the same action?

Tags: animation

Currently, I have a mage and a broom. When the mage is *idle* I wish the broom to **disappear** and when the mage is *flying* I want the broom to **reappear**. I have been using the insert keyframe shortcut for broom visibility and I have been struggling to have it in the same action as the mage's armature.

Is it even possible to animate an armature and object on the same action?

Note: This is for a game so I want those two to work with each other unless there is an easier way.

Comment: can you share some images?

Answer (score 0):

A single action can animate a single armature, but an armature can animate as many objects as you want, so simply add some bones to control the broom with the armature of the mage.